# Script doesn't draw lines by coordinates on Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying use Canvas to let user draw on them on PC or smartphone. I can't understand why this script does not work.
The script does not give any error. The coordinates are set correctly. I tried to set it manually, but even so nothing appeared on Canvas.
I'm not long ago started learn HTML and JS, so may be here some sort of stupid mistake.

Script start working when page loaded and waiting for user input by mouse or touch.
Then takes coordinats of mouse or finger and set it like start point after mouse/finger move it take coordinat and set end point.

```js
        function waitingForUserInput()
        {
            let canvas = document.getElementById("signature-canvas")
            let canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
            canvasContext.lineWidth = 2;
            canvasContext.strokeStyle = "black";
            let isCanvasArea = false;

            let currentX = 0;
            let currentY = 0;

            let previosX = 0;
            let previosY = 0;

            canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (event) {
                    isCanvasArea = true;
                    currentX = event.screenX;
                    currentY = event.screenY;

                    
            }, false);

            canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {

                    if(isCanvasArea)
                    {
                        previosX = currentX;
                        previosY = currentY;

                        currentX = event.screenX;
                        currentY = event.screenY;

                        drawOnCanvas(previosX, previosY, currentX, currentY, canvasContext);

                    }
            }, false);

            canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (event) {
                isCanvasArea = false;
            }, false);
            canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (event) {
                isCanvasArea = false;
            }, false);

            canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function (event) {
                isCanvasArea = true;
                currentX = event.touches[0].screenX;
                currentY = event.touches[0].screenY;
            }, false);
            canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", function (event) {
                if(isCanvasArea)
                {
                    previosX = currentX;
                    previosY = currentY;

                    currentX = event.touches[0].screenX;
                    currentY = event.touches[0].screenY;

                    drawOnCanvas(previosX, previosY, currentX, currentY, canvasContext);
                }
            }, false);
            canvas.addEventListener("touchend", function (event) {
                isCanvasArea = false;
            }, false);
            

        }

        function drawOnCanvas(startX, startY, endX, endY, canvasContext)
        {
            canvasContext.beginPath();
            canvasContext.moveTo(startX, startY);
            canvasContext.lineTo(endX, endY);
            canvasContext.fill();
            canvasContext.closePath();

        }
```

```css
        .draw-canvas
        {
            position: relative;
            width: 600px;
            height: 600px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 5px;
            background-color: blanchedalmond;
        }
        .draw-canvas__canvas
        {
            position: relative;
            top: 145px;
            left: 145px;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin: 5px;
            background-color: white;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .draw-canvas__button
        {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            top: 250px;
        }

        .save-button
        {
            
            left: 5px;
        }

        .delete-button
        {
            right: 5px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body onload="waitingForUserInput()">
    <div class="draw-canvas">
        <canvas id="signature-canvas" class="draw-canvas__canvas"></canvas>
        <button class="draw-canvas__button save-button">Save</button>
        <button class="draw-canvas__button delete-button">Delete</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't have good words to describe my mood, because i noticed that Canvas have limited quantity of pixels by Y-axis. You can delete in my example **padding** in **.draw-canvas** and **top**, **left** and **margin**, then delete **height** in **.draw-canvas__canvas**, check coordinates in right-bottom corner, expend this canvas to 200px or whatever you want and check coordinates from which script begin paint. This is same 150px! If somebody know why this happaning please anwser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the following in your code:

1. Instead of `canvasContext.fill();` use `canvasContext.stroke();`
2. Change all of the `event.screenX` to `event.layerX` (for both X and Y obviously)